# Facebook CDN CORS Issue

Tags: facebook

I am trying to implementing downloading a messenger attachment(hold in Facebook CDN) from my website, but Facebook CDN enables CORS policy, it is not allowed to be accessed by outside except its allowed domain.

Does anyone know how can I download it from the Facebook server in my website?

[image]

Comment: Please paste the code that is causing the issue.

Comment: Why are you making an AJAX request for this URL in the first place? Just _redirect_ the user’s browser to that URL, that should trigger the download automatically (provided Facebook sets appropriate response headers.)